# Build go dependencies in separate Docker layer

Tags: docker, go, dockerfile, go-modules

I'm trying to speed up Docker builds of my Go app. Right now, it's spending maybe 60s just building dependencies (it's a k8s controller, so there are a lot).

One very important constraint: my project depends on private GitHub repos. I do `go mod vendor` outside `docker build`, where I have creds for the repos set up.

My Dockerfile right now is roughly:

```
FROM golang:1.12

WORKDIR /src

COPY . .
RUN go build -mod=vendor
...
```

Even without having to download the deps, that build takes a while because it rebuilds several hundred packages every `docker build`.

What I'd like to do is something like:

```
FROM golang:1.12

WORKDIR /src

# these shouldn't change very often
COPY go.mod go.sum vendor ./
RUN go build -mod=vendor <all dependency packages>

COPY . .
RUN go build -mod=vendor
...
```

I tried parsing `go.mod`, but of course that lists modules, not packages. I tried `go list` but never managed to get a working incantation.

Comment: Take a look at multistage build from Docker. Another approach is build your dependencies in a different container, publish it , and use it as a base container for your application building container.

Comment: @atayenel I'm using multistage builds, just don't think they're relevant?

Comment: @atayenel And I'm not sure how base images help. Are you saying I could have a base image that has an old build with perhaps up to date dependencies? Building that base image has the same problem

Comment: Yes, but you are not updating your deps too much( your words) , you just build it once and next iterations will use it until you update your deps again

Comment: keep an eye open on the process of modularizing K8S. Once that's done, using a local module repository (like Athens or Artifactory) and a central module repository (like GoCenter) wil do magic to your build times.

Comment: @fons, why not use another builder docker image which is run to process the build. So instead of using `docker build`, you use `docker run` to create a build inside docker image. This gives you a chance to save the build cache back to the host and re-use those folders during the next build

Answer (score 2):

I've got a nasty hack that seems to work:

```
FROM golang:1.12

WORKDIR /src

COPY go.mod go.sum ./
COPY vendor/ ./vendor
RUN go build -mod=vendor $(cat deps|grep -v mypackage | grep -v internal)

COPY . .
RUN go build -mod=vendor
...
```

```
go list -f '{{join .Deps "\n"}}'  > deps
docker build .
```

Comment: May be a bit less of a hack would be to override `GOCACHE` before building the deps in such a way so that they end up being a part of your Docker build context, then copy them over, and then override this env. var accordingly in the image. Please see [this](https://golang.org/doc/go1.11#gocache) and follow the links. Note that the `-x` command-line option to the `go {build|install}` commands makes them chatty about what they are doing (and where they look for files etc).

Comment: @kostix that's not a bad idea. I'm running on a Mac though. I assume `GOCACHE` isn't platform independent?

Comment: It's dependent in the sense the location of the user's home directory is. But note that the `go` tool has a built-in default for this variable (whih can be known by running `go env` or `go env GOCACHE`), and this default can be overridden by the environment variable with the same name. (It actually works for any variable known by `go env`).

Comment: I mean platform-dependent as in "packages compiled in the cache for darwin won't work on Linux". Surely those aren't portable between OSes.

Comment: I beleive "it's not true either way" ;-) The reason is that the compiled packages are not merely lumped in a common place but are rather separated there by the `GOOS` and `GOARCH` under which they were built. It means two things: 1) packages compiled natively on Mac OS won't "spoil" the cache mounted on Linux as the compiler told to build native code _there_ simply won't make use of those cached packages; 2) Packages _cross-compiled_ on MacOS X, can be used in the image.

Comment: Another problem with this solution is that the go compiler and git are required to be installed in the host OS

Answer (score 0):

Docker documentation has a guide specific to Go docker images ([Build your Go image](https://docs.docker.com/language/golang/build-images/)).

It works as follows:

```
# Layer for dependency installation
COPY go.mod go.sum ./
RUN go mod download
# Layer for app build
COPY . .
RUN go build -o main .
```